# Multiple approvals using 2010 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, approval-process

This is my list:

[image]

I tried amending the workflow for multiple (2) approvals:

[image]

[image]

The workflow seems to stop after updating the approval status column.

There is no error as it was published.

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the workflow stop at “Find Manager of user” action at “When a Task Completes” step?

Whether the “Update list item” action works as expected?

If so, make sure you have configured User Profile Service Application and started sync user profile with SharePoint.

If the issue exists, you can also add “Log to history list” action behind each action and check if the previous action is executed.

Comment: I log to history list, after the task outcome is approved but nothing shows up instead, the outgoing email cant be sent error. But when I tried sending emails outside the approval process, it works